# How do I activate python anaconda and run script from regular command prompt in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to create an automated job to navigate to a network share and from there to run a Python script but permissions are a little wonky. If I start python first, it can't find the share. However, I found that if I start an Anaconda prompt first, it can navigate to the share and execute no problem. Here is the sequence of commands in a batch file:

```
z:
CD Python
python ImportTool.py LocalCommands.txt
```

Unless there is a way to call an anaconda prompt directly from Task Scheduler, I figured I would need to add a line to the batch file to convert the command prompt to an Anaconda prompt. This works:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
```

The problem is once this runs, it ends the batch so the other commands don't run. From the new command prompt if I call the remaining lines in another batch file it works but that means a second call. This has to work in a single batch as a schedule job.

So my question is, how can I modify my batch file to get my anaconda prompt and still be able to run the remaining commands without a second call? TIA

Comment: But why should you need Anaconda to run in the first place? There's no good reason that Python shouldn't be able to find the network share on its own, and from your description it seems as if you would agree that's true. So maybe pick apart `activate.bat` to see what the magic line is? One specific issue that's bitten me before is multiple Python installs; perhaps there is an odd version of Python in your `PATH` variable, and the Anaconda activation remedies that...?

Comment: One other note (which also doesn't answer your actual question, sorry) is that I also use Python on Win10. I found Anaconda to be more and more of a hassle as time went on (Conda package manager would often hang up when upgrading modules), so I eventually ditched Anaconda and switched to [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) instead, and I'm very glad I did. It provides all the good stuff of Anaconda (Jupyter, Numpy, Matplotlib) and is a portable install, so side-steps all the Anaconda hassles I had. I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug through the various calls. For some reason calling the conda.exe app is what throws off the batch execution. It isn't necessary to call, however, if you add all the necessary paths for anaconda. My final batch file looks like this:

```
SET PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;%PATH%
z:
CD Python
python ImportTool.py LocalCommands.txt
```

That does the job